# How to change how disabled dropdown in form is rendered

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have 2 forms, the first of which has a dropdown which lets users a driver: Bob, Jim, Jack.... Assume the user opts for Bob and saves.

```
class RouteUpdate(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model= Route
    fields= [
        'route',
        'driver',
        ...
```

In the second form, I need to display Bob but the field must not be editable. Readonly isn't an option as this allows viewing (if not selection) of the other options.

Disabling the field works, but it is still rendered as a dropdown list (disabled).

[image]

Any suggestions on how to solve this. I'd be happy if there's a way to simply 
render "Bob as a variable in the template rather than as a form field. Alternatively how can I format the field?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand very well, do you want to delete that dropdown and assume the value in the views or just show in the template like a label?

Comment: Showing the value as a label would be acceptable since no editing is allowed. Actually, it would be useful to be able to show data from other model rows on the form as well. For example,  each route has a target number of stops. I'd like to be able to show the percentage based on planned stops / target stops * 100. I think it's the same requirement.

Comment: well, I don't know that, but publish your view and template

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the Field docs, you can do what you want:

In your case you can add a field in the class

```
class RouteUpdate(forms.ModelForm):

    the_driver = forms.CharField(required=False, label='The Driver', disabled=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RouteUpdate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # here you can decide the name of your driver based on other fields/model
        self.fields['the_driver'].initial = 'The name of the driver'

    class Meta:
        model= Route
        fields= [
            'route',
            ...
```

If you need to pass a value to the form to construct the name of the driver, you can do that on the init. On your view, get the request.user and get the name from that and pass it

```
class RouteUpdate(forms.ModelForm):

    the_driver = forms.CharField(required=False, label='The Driver', disabled=True)

    def __init__(self, username=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # the super is called without username
        super(RouteUpdate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        username = username or 'default name'
        self.fields['the_driver'].initial = username

    class Meta:
        model= Route
        fields= [
            'route',
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you. This works well, but isn't quite meeting my needs because of another requirement. The initial fields value ('The name of the driver') from the example in my case varies, depending on the name of the logged in user. How can I pass the logged in user_id in?